authlib + mailchimp oauth2: invalid_client: client_id parameter missing
I'm building out an OAuth2 Factory using authlib and FastAPI because my upstream application needs to authenticate with multiple providers.
The authentication factory works well with all providers except for Mailchimp.
I don't want to use the mailchimp_marketing client library (for a few different reasons).
When I initiate the OAuth flow in the browser, I ultimately get the following error in my callback function on token = await oauth_client.authorize_access_token(request) (exchanging the authorization code for an access token). And I've confirmed that "client_id=settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_ID," is actually set.
"GET /oauth/mailchimp/callback?state=ABC123XYZ&code=ABC123XYZ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal 

Server Error
...
2024-07-07 16:48:30   File "/app/app/api/oauth.py", line 25, in callback
2024-07-07 16:48:30     token = await oauth_client.authorize_access_token(request)
2024-07-07 16:48:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/authlib/integrations/starlette_client/apps.py", line 81, in authorize_access_token
2024-07-07 16:48:30     token = await self.fetch_access_token(**params, **kwargs)
2024-07-07 16:48:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/authlib/integrations/base_client/async_app.py", line 125, in fetch_access_token
2024-07-07 16:48:30     token = await client.fetch_token(token_endpoint, **params)
2024-07-07 16:48:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/authlib/integrations/httpx_client/oauth2_client.py", line 138, in _fetch_token
2024-07-07 16:48:30     return self.parse_response_token(resp)
2024-07-07 16:48:30   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/client.py", line 344, in parse_response_token
2024-07-07 16:48:30     raise self.oauth_error_class(
2024-07-07 16:48:30 authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.OAuthError: invalid_client: client_id parameter missing

Here's my relevant code:
provider_factory.py
# app/services/provider_factory.py

from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
from app.core.config import settings
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

class ProviderFactory:
    oauth = OAuth()
    oauth.register(
        name='mailchimp',
        client_id=settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=settings.MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorize_url='https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize',
        access_token_url='https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
        api_base_url='https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/',
    )

    oauth.register(
        name='another_provider',
        client_id=settings.ANOTHER_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=settings.ANOTHER_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorize_url='https://auth.another.com/oauth2/authorize',
        access_token_url='https://auth.another.com/oauth2/token',
        client_kwargs={'scope': '...'},
    )

    @staticmethod
    def get_provider_service(provider_name: str, db: Session):
        from app.models.provider import Provider
        provider = db.query(Provider).filter_by(name=provider_name).first()
        if not provider:
            raise ValueError(f"No provider found with name: {provider_name}")

        if provider.name == 'mailchimp':
            from app.services.mailchimp import MailchimpProvider
            return MailchimpProvider(db, provider)
        elif provider.name == 'another':
            from app.services.another import AnotherProvider
            return AnotherProvider(db, provider)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported provider: {provider.name}")

    @staticmethod
    def get_oauth_client(provider_name: str):
        return getattr(ProviderFactory.oauth, provider_name)

    @staticmethod
    def get_token_url(provider_name: str) -> str:
        if provider_name == 'mailchimp':
            return 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token'
        elif provider_name == 'another':
            return 'https://auth.another.com/oauth2/token'
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unsupported provider")

    @staticmethod
    def create_provider(db: Session, provider_name: str):
        return ProviderFactory.get_provider_service(provider_name, db)

oauth.py
# app/api/oauth.py

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, Request
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from app.db.session import get_db
from app.models.provider import Provider
from app.models.user import User
from app.models.connection import Connection
from app.core.logger import logger
from app.services.provider_factory import ProviderFactory

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/{provider}/login")
async def login(provider: str, request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('callback', provider=provider)
    return await ProviderFactory.get_oauth_client(provider).authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

@router.get("/{provider}/callback")
async def callback(provider: str, request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    logger.info(f"Provider: {provider}")
    logger.info(f"Request query params: {request.query_params}")

    oauth_client = ProviderFactory.get_oauth_client(provider)
    token = await oauth_client.authorize_access_token(request)
    if not token:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Failed to get access token")

    provider_record = db.query(Provider).filter_by(name=provider).first()
    if not provider_record:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Provider not found")

    provider_service = ProviderFactory.get_provider_service(provider, db)

    # Get user information from the provider
    user_info = await provider_service.get_account_info(token)
    logger.info(f"User info: {user_info}")

    ...

    return {"status": "success", "provider": provider}

mailchimp.py
# app/services/mailchimp.py

import requests
from app.services.base_provider import BaseProvider
from app.models.list import List
from app.models.list_properties import ListProperties

class MailchimpProvider(BaseProvider):
    tokens_expire = False

    async def get_account_info(self, token: dict):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token["access_token"]}'}
            async with session.get('https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/metadata', headers=headers) as response:
                return await response.json()

    async def get_lists(self):
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.provider.access_token}'
        }
        response = requests.get('https://api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists', headers=headers)
        lists_data = response.json().get('lists', [])

        for list_data in lists_data:
            ...

    ...

Any ideas? Hoping that I'm just missing something small.

Per In authlib, does authorize_access_token require the explicit passing of client_id and client_secret?, I just had to add
client_kwargs = {
    'token_endpoint_auth_method': 'client_secret_post',
}

"The default token_endpoint_auth_method is client_secret_basic, which will send client credentials in HTTP Authorization header. However...it seems that the provider needs client_id and client_secret in payload, which should be client_secret_post."
